# When I wrote text to a File, why don't I see the Text when I open the file?

Tags: android, file-io, android-sdcard

I wrote an android app that just outputs a text and date to a file on the SD card.

```
public class MyWastedTimeActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        EditText ujET=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
        Button gomb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final String ujString=ujET.getText().toString();
        gomb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    commitToFile(ujString);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


    }

private void commitToFile(String mit) throws IOException {
    String aktIdo = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
     String kiIr =aktIdo+" "+mit+"\n";

     FileOutputStream fos = null;
     ObjectOutputStream out = null;


      File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();


       fos = new FileOutputStream(  root + "/" +"idom.txt" ,true);

       out = new ObjectOutputStream( fos );
       out.writeObject( kiIr );
       out.close();   


     }
}
```

The problem is when i open the "idom.txt"-file on my pc it gives me :Ԁt䴎牡ㄠⰸ㈠㄰′갊í琅฀慍⁲㠱‬〲㈱ਠ when its really not what i wrote ...Any suggestion?

Comment: Try writing `aktIdo` to your console or a log file. I'm sure what you're getting isn't a String...

Answer (score 0):

You have used `ObjectOutputStream` Class. The method writeObject is used to write an object to the stream. Look at this Reference [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html). It is going to write in binary format which is not human readble form.

I Suggest you to use `PrintWriter` Class. PrintWriter is one of the character-based classes.
Here is a nice [example](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=329).